# Play - PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, playframework

I have e three table :

1) Sanitation
2)UnitData
3)Data

The id of Data (PK ) is used as a FK on both Sanitation and UnitData table . So , I think , if I have to delete any data from Data table - at first I have to delete data from Sanitation and UnitData table. Here is my controller:

```
 @ExternalRestrictions("Edit Data")
        public static int delete(Long id) {

            int confirm = 1;

            if(request.isAjax()) {

            List<Sanitation> sanitation1 = Sanitation.find("data_id = ?", id).fetch();

                if(sanitation1.size()!=0){

                    Sanitation sanitation = sanitation1.get(0);
                    Logger.info("sanitationget: " + sanitation1.get(0));

                    sanitation.delete();
                    sanitation.refresh();
                }


                List<UnitData> unitData1 = UnitData.find("data_id = ?", id).fetch();

               Logger.info("unidatasize: " + unitData1.size());
                  for(int i=0;i<unitData1.size();i++){


                      UnitData unitdata = unitData1.get(i);
                      unitdata.delete();
                      unitdata.refresh();
                  }

                Data data = Data.findById(id);

                Logger.info("data: "+ data);
                data.delete();
                data.refresh();

 return confirm;

}
```

And the models are:

1) Data model:

```
 public String submissionId;

    public String groupTagName;

    public String respondentId;

    public Boolean isVisited;
    public Date resolveDate;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    public SchoolInformation schools;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    public Ngo ngo;

    public int iteration = 1;

    public int approvalStatus;

    public int approvalState;

    otherwise true */
    public Boolean isFarmerActive = true;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    public Form form;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public byte[] xml;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public byte[] dataSpecificXml;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    public User sender;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })

    public Role senderRole;

    public Boolean webEntry = false;

    @Transient
    public List items;
    public Date received;

    public Date startTime;
    public Date endTime;

    public String[] audioData;

    public Double latitude;
    public Double longitude;
    public Double accuracy;
    public String image;
    public Boolean isExtracted = false;
    public String webOrMob = "";
```

2) UnitData model:

```
@Required
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    public Data data;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    public Form form;

    @Required
    public String titleVar;
    public String title;
    public String type;
    public String valueVar;
    @Column(length=1023)
    public String value;
    public String extraValue;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    public FormResource formResource;


    @Min(0)
    public int iterationNo;
```

3) Sanitation model:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    public Data data;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    public Form form;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    public User sender;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    public SchoolInformation school;

    public String month = "";
    public String res_type = "";
    public String num_toilet_unusable = "";
    public String why_toilet_unusable = "";
    public String toilet_clean_interval = "";

    public String harpic = "";
    public String is_sanitation_prob_informed = "";
    public String how_informed_sanitation_prob = "";
    public String how_informed_sanitation_prob_other = "";

    public String took_step_sanitation_prob = "";
    public String rank_sanitation = "";
```

When I am trying to delete(click on the delete button) it shows error in **sanitation.delete()** line:

> PersistenceException occured :
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not
>   execute JDBC batch update

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is it me or is the entity `Sanitation` trying to delete itself?

Comment: yes! @JackFlamp

Comment: some foreign key constraint violated? hard to know. Add the code for `sanitation.delete()` method.